# Tensorboard instances listed as running while the actual processes are defunct

Tags: python, jupyter, tensorboard

In Jupyter notebook:
`notebook.list()` shows:

> Known TensorBoard instances:
>
> - port 6006: logdir /home/ai-mining/AI_Mining/logs/train (started 21:49:59 ago; pid 32470)
> - port 6006: logdir /home/ai-mining/AI_Mining/logs/ (started 1:20:19 ago; pid 34361)

and if do `!kill 32470`
`!kill 34361`

> /bin/sh: 1: kill: No such process

> /bin/sh: 1: kill: No such process

Indeed if I list the processes for tensorboard in the terminal:`ps -ax |grep tensorboard`

> 3788 pts/9    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto tensorboard

there are no such processes to kill.
I should mention that the logs in log_dir where the data is stored are empty.
Also the only option in this case is to reload `%reload_ext tensorboard` and not load. This is not working since the actual process is dead.

How do I clean the logs listed by `notebook.list()` or in any way solve my problem? I cannot connect to a tensorboard now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what solved my problem in the end. If there is a nicer way to solve this I would be interested.
The tensorboard keeps track of the process ids (even defunct ones) in the directory `/tmp/.tensorboard-info`. If this folder is not in the /tmp folder, one can list the temporary location using

```
import tempfile
import os
import shutil 
path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), ".tensorboard-info") 
shutil.rmtree(path) ##this removes the folder recursively
!fuser 6006/tcp -k #clear the port
```

I removed the `.tensorboard-info` folder, cleared the logs-dir folder and restarted the Tensorboard.

To avoid cleaning this over and over, one can save the log files in separate folders in the logs-dir folder and keep only one instance of the Tensorboard running and just reload it if needed. Create new folders using:

```
import datetime
TensorBoard(histogram_freq=1, log_dir='/home/my_project_directory/logs/'+ datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
```

Each run will be listed in Tensorboard separately and can be vizualized.